# MATLAB: How do I pass a parameter to a function?

Tags: matlab, parameters, function, calculus

I have the following function:

```
function ypdiff = ypdiff(t,y)
    a = 0.01;
    b = 0.1;
    ypdiff(1) = -a*y(1)*y(2);
    ypdiff(2) = b*y(1)*y(2)-b*y(2);
    ypdiff(3) = b*y(2);
    ypdiff = [ypdiff(1) ypdiff(2) ypdiff(3)]';
```

If I want to solve this, I would call the ode45 function as follows:

```
[t y] = ode45(@ypdiff, [to tf], yo);
```

But if I want to pass a parameter to this function, how would I use the ode45 function? Specifically, I am trying for the following formulation:

```
function ypdiff = ypdiff(t,y,u)
    a = 0.01;
    b = 0.1;
    ypdiff(1) = -a*u*y(1)*y(2);
    ypdiff(2) = b*u*y(1)*y(2)-b*y(2);
    ypdiff(3) = b*u*y(2);
    ypdiff = [ypdiff(1) ypdiff(2) ypdiff(3)]';
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) in matlab (similar to lambda functions in other languages):

```
u = 1.2;
[t y] = ode45(@(t, y) ypdiff(t, y, u), [to tf], yo);
```

Comment: Great... Thanks a lot.. However, I couldn't get it working until I removed the ':' character

Comment: yep, that was a typo, sorry ;)

Comment: why do i need  `ode45(@(t, y) ypdiff(t, y, u)`, but not just `ode45(@ypdiff(u))`. Why t,y is needed?