# Matlab: Why in passing additional arguments in ode45 i need to pass `(t,y)` as well?

Tags: matlab

In [MATLAB: How do I pass a parameter to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256229/matlab-how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-function),

it is said that if i want to pass the parameter `u`, i need to use anonymous function:

```
u = 1.2;
[t y] = ode45(@(t, y) ypdiff(t, y, u), [to tf], yo);
```

Originally, without passing parameter `u`, the ode line reads:

`[t y] = ode45(@ypdiff, [to tf], yo);`, where `@ypdiff` just creates a function handle.

Why if we want to pass `u` only, we also need to include `t` and `y` in the creation of  anonymous function `@(t, y) ypdiff(t, y, u)`, but not something like `@ypdiff(u)`?

Answer (score 2):

Simply appending `@` to the front of a function creates a function handle *not* an anonymous function. This function handle implicitly forwards all input arguments onto the function.

What you need is a function handle to an anonymous function (since it accepts inputs and performs an action or calls another function). In this case, it does *not* implicitly pass inputs therefore you need to explicitly receive input arguments and then use them (or not) within the anonymous function.

```
@(t, y)ypdiff(t, y, u)
```

The only exception to this rule is that some graphics objects will accept a cell array in place of a callback function which accept a function handle as the first element and any additional parameters as the second, but this is not the case for `ode45`.

```
{@ypdiff, u}
```

Comment: but why is t also needed when the derivative does not depend on t?

Comment: @kww Well you wrote it that way in your initial question. What inputs does `ypdiff` expect?

Comment: but in case `ypdiff` does not depend on `t`, can `@(t, y)ypdiff(t, y, u)` become `@(y)ypdiff(y, u)`. My objective is to pass `u`. And in MATLAB, it highlights i use `~` to replace `t` in subfunction `ypdiff`.

Comment: @kww If `ypdiff` only takes two inputs then you can do `@(t,y)ypdiff(y,u)`. You still have to make the anonymous function accept `t`, but you just don't use it when calling `ypdiff`